# How to open page speed tool in ubuntu

Tags: installation

I've installed pagespeed toolkit in my system. But couldn't find the icon to open the pagespeed anywhere in the system

I am newbie at ubuntu . Please see the below url for the pagespeed instructions

http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/download.html

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the page you've linked to, it seems that page speed is a browser extension for Chrome and Firefox.

Which browser do you use to access the internet? Open that browser, and look through the installed addons to find PageSpeed. If you use chrome, click the Wrench menu and go to `Tools > Extensions`. If you use Firefox, go to `Tools > Addons` in the main menu. If you don't see it there, go back to the page, and download the extension for your particular browser.

Comment: But I've installed it for the Apache

Comment: Do you have an apache server? I'm afraid I don't quite understand what you're hoping to achieve with PageSpeed. The apache version seems to be designed to help you speed up your web server.

Comment: . Oh , I am sorry ,perhaps I had mistaken , finally I've seen the light.Thanks for the advise , Will try the browser addon